# Image quality loss while resizing image in C# for asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize an image and save it with the following snippet code. It works fine but some images lose quality after the resize. When I checked, the original images looked fine and only the ones which were resized had a low quality. I don't know how I can improve the image quality while resizing it.

```
System.Drawing.Image NewImage = FullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(NewWidth, MaxHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
// Clear handle to original file so that we can overwrite it if necessary
FullsizeImage.Dispose();
// Save resized picture
//NewImage.Save(NewFile);

if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpeg")
{
      NewImage.Save(NewFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Please, help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ResizeImage
/// </summary>
public class ResizeImage
{
    public static Image Resize(Image imgToResize, int h, int w)
    {
        Size size = new Size(w, h);

        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);

        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (Image)b;
    }
}
```

Also, You can use this code to option image quality:

```
graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality; 
graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
```

Like [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/04/02/resizing-images-without-loss-of-quality.aspx).

Comment: You should `Dispose` the `Bitmap` too. Rather than explicitly calling `Dispose`, a `using` statement is the preferred way of disposing because it guarantees clean-up in the case of an `Exception` occurring.

Comment: Ah. Perhaps disposing the Bitmap isn't such a good idea, seeing as that is what is returned. There should be a caveat to the user of this method that the returned Image should be disposed when finished.

Answer (score 0):

With image resizing, you should also keep in mind few more things (rules of thumb, not a gospel as it depends on what you're doing etc.)...

- keep stored in Db (or wherever) the largest image you can get your hands on (and providing your Db/storage can allow for that). i.e. you can make thumbnails on the fly or cache them or something, but the largest image is the 'raw model' sort of,
- down-scale - if possible - don't scale up, as that's never going to be as good,
- keep the 'proportion' of images,
- be careful of the image manipulation, it has to be done right to avoid adding noise etc.
- the image format you're using (for saving or temp format etc.) is also very important, that can also  ruin your image, as different formats have different algorithms and make / sacrifice different parameters of your image (whether that is the colors or the details etc.),
- use as little 'conversions' as possible - so keep the original, do simple scaling on it - and keep in memory while you can, e.g. don't save/load etc.

hope this helps,